# Compare two strings meaningfully in Java

Tags: java, string, numbers, double, long-integer

I've two strings which I need to compare, but I want to compare them meaningfully such that when they are numbers their actual value should be compared. So far I've tried the following solution:

```
String str1 = "-0.6";
String str2 = "-.6";
if (NumberUtils.isNumber(str1) && NumberUtils.isNumber(str2)) {
    Number num1 = NumberUtils.createNumber(str1);
    Number num2 = NumberUtils.createNumber(str2);
    System.out.println(num1.equals(num2));
} else {
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
}
```

This works as both are converted to `double`s.
But this won't work in this case where:

```
String str1 = "6";
String str2 = "6.0";
```

Is there any easy way to do this, or will I have to write my own Comparator?

Comment: And how do you act when one string is not a number of some sort?

Comment: Can't you make the `createNumber()` method to always return `Double` for numbers?

Comment: This means that string is not meant for numerical comparisons such as this. You should go with convrting to double and compare them as you have mentioned.

Comment: Does it solve using something like `Number num1 = 0. + NumberUtils.createNumber(str1);`? The same for `num2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the general-purpose [`createNumber(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#createNumber(java.lang.String)), force them to `double`s using [`createDouble(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#createDouble(java.lang.String)):

```
String str1 = "-0.6";
String str2 = "-.6";
if (NumberUtils.isNumber(str1) && NumberUtils.isNumber(str2)) {
    Double d1 = NumberUtils.createDouble(str1);
    Double d2 = NumberUtils.createDouble(str2);
    System.out.println(d1.equals(d2));
} else {
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `BigDecimal` for this:

```
final BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(str1);
final BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(str2);
return b1.compareTo(b2) == 0;
```

Comment: Why big decimal for such smaller numbers that are mentioned in the code snippet ?

Comment: what happens if one the strings is not a number?

Comment: @DegenSharew I mentioned that first thing in the comments

Comment: @sakthisundar because precision; at least, with a `BigDecimal` you don't get any surprises!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Double.parseDouble(String)` instead. It throws the `NumberFormatException`, which can be caught to inform you that you should not compare them as numbers.

```
try {
    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(str1);
    Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(str2);

    //Now you have your doubles
} catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    //Could not compare as numbers, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested on the comment one of the string could be a `number` and the other not or vice versa or both could be a `string` so instead of checking if the strings are number strings I will go using `try catch` block.

Like this:

```
try{
    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(str1);
    Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(str2);
    System.out.println(d1.equals(d2));
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){

    System.out.println(num1.equals(num2));

}
```

---

This first tries to compare them as numbers but if at least one of them is not a number string it will fallback to string comparison in the `catch` block.